# With two joined trapezoidal prisms, calculate the local roll angle of one, when rotation is applied to another

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation

Given two connected trapezoidal prisms are connected as follows:
[image]

I can apply a rotation to the prism on the left by rotating about the local X-Axis (top of the prism)   -    As they are connected the prism on the right will be affected:

[image]

My question is:  If I do not refer to the first prism, how would I calculate the applied transforms to the second prism in isolation?

I know:
a)  The rotation angle about the X-Axis applied to the first prism
b)  The local rotation about the Z-axis of the second prism to make the two prisms join

I would like to calculate the rotation about X & Y axis on the second prism.

Comment: This depends on how you define "rotation about the $X$ and $Y$ axes on the second prism" ("axes", pronounced AKS-EES or AKS-EEZ, depending on dialects, is the plural of "axis"). It sounds like you are looking for a pair of rotation angles. But rotations are specified by $3$-dimensional matrices, and [converting that to rotation angles depends on what order you make those simple rotations. And generally it requires three angles, not just two.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)

Comment: I shall study your wiki link and see if I can find the answer here. For clarification,  if we imagine the rotational origin for each prism is the the centre of it's front top edge. 
The pitch angle of prism 1 is modified.  Simply referring to the second prism (excluding translation) I would like to describe the rotation applied to the second prism.  
As you say, this is in three dimensions, my question was not clearly worded before. I guess I do not know where to start. It is the calculation of the roll angle applied to the second which I am struggling with

Comment: I already get that you have global coordinates as shown, and body coordinates for each of the two prisms. What you need to do is find the equation for the $x$-axis of the body coordinates of the first prism in the body coordinates of the second prism. Use [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to find the rotation matrix in the 2nd prism coordinates, and then interpret them as roll, pitch, yaw, as per [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations) (though you may have to swap signs per your definition).